# How to import sqlite from plain text dump?

Tags: sql, sqlite, import

[This excellent XKCD article](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results) about color-poll data at the very end mentions:

> If you have ideas and want to analyze these results further, I’ve posted the raw data as an SQLite dump [here](http://xkcd.com/color/colorsurvey.tar.gz) (84 MB .tar.gz file).

In the archive you will find plain .TXT file `mainsurvey_sqldump.txt` which is SQLite dump. I work on MAC and would like to turn this dump into a database. **How can I do it and what friendly software can I use?** I am very beginner at SQLite and DB. I tried **DB Browser for SQLite** (at `sqlitebrowser.org`) but could not figure out how to import the dump (what I tried runs forever).

Thank you very much for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite comes with a command line tool to manage databases that is called `sqlite3`. You can use it to create a new database and import a dump in it. The following command will do both of these things:

```
sqlite3 /path/to/database.sqlite < /path/to/mainsurvey_sqldump.txt
```

After that, you can find the database in `/path/to/database.sqlite` (it will be a single file). After that, if you don't mind working in the terminal, you can open the database as follows:

```
sqlite3 /path/to/database.sqlite
```

You can then type sql queries in the `sqlite` prompt.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.